# nuxt: passing hidden data to route

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-link

i need to pass **two** data via `Nuxt-link` ,

first id `Id` used to get single Post and must be `hidden`

another is `title` used to be in `URL` because of SEO

```
<NuxtLink to="localePath({ path: `/blog/${post.title}` })">
show Post
</NuxtLink>
``

i have abode code and I don't now how to pass `ID`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create files like that:

[image: Pages directory]

Then redirect to blog post:

```
<NuxtLink
  :to="{
    name: 'blog-title',
    params: { title: 'vue', id: 123 },
  }"
>
  Go to Blog post page and pass user id
</NuxtLink>
```

And get id in blog page file:

```
this.$route.params.id
```

It is hidden, because file name contains only **_title**.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-fast-d2r5k?file=/pages/blog/_title.vue

**But** to be honest I don't really understand what you want to do. You should get id from title. Now if somebody gets link to that article:
*www.[xyz].com/blog/vue*,
they won't get id, because it is hidden and it is passed only if they are redirected from that specific previous page. The same if user opens this link in new (blank) card. It will be rendered on server which won't see that hidden id.

Check this:

https://d2r5k.sse.codesandbox.io/ (**homepage > blog = it works**)
https://d2r5k.sse.codesandbox.io/blog/vue (**blog = it doesn't work - there is not id**)

Comment: thnx, you mean , i have to pass the title in the URL then get the id by URL and requset to API with that id ?

Comment: @kevin exactly. If you don't want to pass id in URL, that's the only way. It must work when user gets link directly to blog post.